# can't upload images to the server, how do I fix this?

Tags: php, mysql, flutter, upload

I uploaded the image to the server, did not press upload, then went to check the post created for storing the image on the server, it turned out that the uploaded image was not found but no error message is displayed, only the image is not displayed in the server

Code saveProblem

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);

// Response object structure
$response = new stdClass;
$response->status = null;
$response->message = null;

// Uploading file
$destination_dir = "Problem/";
$base_filename = basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$target_file = $destination_dir . $base_filename;

if(!$_FILES["file"]["error"])
{
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {        
        $response->status = true;
        $response->message = "File uploaded successfully";

    } else {

        $response->status = false;
        $response->message = "File uploading failed";
    }    
} 
else
{
    $response->status = false;
    $response->message = "File uploading failed";
}

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($response);
```

Code uploadImage

```
Future<Null> uploadImage() async {
    Random random = Random();
    int i = random.nextInt(1000000);
    String nameImage = 'problem$i.jpg';
    print('nameImage = $nameImage, pathImage = ${file!.path}');
    String url = '${MyConstant().domain}/application_water/saveProblem.php';
    try {
      Map<String, dynamic> map = Map();
      map['file'] =
          await MultipartFile.fromFile(file!.path, filename: nameImage);
      FormData formData = FormData.fromMap(map);
      await Dio().post(url, data: formData).then((value) {
        print('Response ==>> $value');
        urlImage = '/application_water/Problem/$nameImage';
        print('urlImage = $urlImage');
      });
    } catch (e) {}
  }
```

Comment: hi, have you tried to use MultipartFile.fromFileSync()? also you need to either print the error in the catch block or display it on the screen.